# How to support grouping in checkbox template for DropDownList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I need checkboxes in a grouped DropDownList
I added checkboxes using various sample templates but the grouping style was corrupted.
What is the correct checkbox template for the DropDownList which also supports Groups?

Comment: What do you mean with grouped `DropDownList` ? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to give you specifics unless you post your code or more details, but generally your situation is possible and easy to achieve.  You just choose your template and put the field you want to group by in the datasource declaration of the dropdown.

```
$("#dropdownList").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        template: $("#CheckboxTemplate").html(),
        dataSource: {
            data: data,
            group: {
                field: "color"
            }
        }
```

I created a Fiddle showing an example of grouping in a Kendo DDL with checkboxes:
http://jsfiddle.net/qfb02x0v/6/

And here is some additional information.  This doc is for the combobox, but it works the exact same as the dropdownlist.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/grouping

If you want the list to stay open and allow for multiple selection, I'd suggest using the multiselect widget instead of a dropdown list.  I created a new fiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/754qb972/

Comment: That is exactly what I need - Thanks.

Comment: Ooops there is one remaining  issue - it closes prematurely on first click of any checkbox., I saw a fix at "http://jsfiddle.net/MNqaT/42/" using "_blur: function () { }," but it does not seem to work here.

Comment: It sounds like you may want the multiselect widget instead of the dropdown.  I updated my answer with a new JSFiddle that demonstrates multiselect.